# Ruby on Rails/React Authentication-- session works in postman but not in localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication, session-cookies

I'm using Ruby on Rails sessions/cookies to authenticate users in my React frontend.

Update: The issue appears to be a blocker on using localhost as it's an unsecure domain. I'm looking for advice on how to allow cookies to be set with the specified localhost in my cors.rb file.

Context:
I have a /login route which creates the session, and a /me route which retrieves the active user's data from the session.

The problem:
In postman, once I've posted login credentials, /me returns the correct user information each time. On the other hand, in localhost on the frontend, logging in works but /me isn't retrieving the user's information. The user is not getting stored.

Error message when frontend context runs /me after log in:

```
Started GET "/me" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-30 14:26:10 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as */*
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `authorize'
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.64ms)
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 17ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 795)
```

Backend code:

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :foods, only: [:index]
  resources :users

  post "/signup", to: "users#create"
  get "/me", to: "users#show"
  post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
  delete "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy"
end
```

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::Cookies

    before_action :authorize

    private

    def authorize
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        render json: {errors: "Not authorized"}, status: :unauthorized unless @current_user
    end
end
```

```
# controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            render json: user
        else
            render json: {errors: "check email and password"}, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    def destroy
        session.delete :user_id
        head :no_content
    end
end
```

```
# controller/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :invalid_record_error
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found_error

    skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
    
    def show
        render json: @current_user
    end

    def create
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
    end

    private
    
    def user_params
        params.permit(:email, :password)
    end

    def invalid_record_error(invalid)
        render json: {errors: invalid.record.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

    def not_found_error(invalid)
        render json: {errors: invalid}, status: :not_found
    end
end
```

Frontend code:

```
// Login.js

import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './../../context/UserContext';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {

    const { updateUser, user } = useContext(UserContext)

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({ email: "", password: "" })
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    // let history = useHistory();

    const handleFormChange = (e) => {
        const key = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value

        setUserData({
            ...userData, [key]: value
        })
    }

    const handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/login', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userData)
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    res.json().then(user => {
                        loginUser(user)
                    })
                    // history.push('/menu')
                }
                else {
                    res.json().then(data => setError(data.errors))
                }
            })

        setUserData({
            email: "",
            password: ""
        })
    }

    const loginUser = (user) => {
        updateUser(user)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {user ?

                <h3>Welcome, {user.email}</h3> :

                <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        value={userData.email}
                        onChange={handleFormChange}
                    />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={userData.password}
                        onChange={handleFormChange}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    {error && <p>{error}</p>}
                </form>
            }

        </div>
    )
}
```

```
// UserContext.js

import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    const updateUser = (value) => {
        setUser(value)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/me')
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    res.json()
                        .then(user => updateUser(user))
                }
                else {
                    res.json().then(data => console.log(data.errors))
                }
            })
    }, [])

    if (user) {
        console.log(user)
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{ user, updateUser }}
        >
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { UserProvider } from './context/UserContext';

ReactDOM.render(
    <UserProvider>
        <App />
    </UserProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Cors information:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "http://localhost:3006"

    resource "*",
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you check if the cookies get sent to the server when you send a request to  `/me` endpoint?

Comment: @EkkoKo I see a Set-Cookie header after logging in, but when I refresh and check the /me request, I don't see anything regarding cookies or sessions. Let me know if there's a better way to check! Thanks for the help

Comment: @EkkoKo ^^ that was in regards to localhost, in postman the session id and cookie are showing after posting to /login and still display when fetching /me

Comment: You can check 2 things:
In the developer settings under application you can see the cookies that are saved on that website,
when you fetch `/me` check for authentication or some data to see that the cookies actually pass and get to the server,

Comment: @EkkoKo Nothing shows up under cookies or session storage after logging in or fetching /me... hmmm

Comment: When you're in localhost do you have a `not secured` message in the serach bar?

Comment: @EkkoKo I don't see that message. I am starting to think it might be a cors issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251503/discussion-between-ekkoko-and-smeliott).